# Get near GameObject from list with respect to player position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this function which return me the near object from my player. it partially working fine but the sometime not return the correct object. is there any alternate way available?

```
GameObject GetNearPoint()
    {
        GameObject minDistObject = null;

        float minDist = Mathf.Infinity;

        for (var i = 0; i < gameObject.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject childGo = gameObject.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            float dist = Vector3.Distance(childGo.transform.position, VRPlayer.transform.position);

            if (dist == 0)
            {
                Debug.Log("equal distnace :: " + childGo.name);
                continue;
            }
            if (dist < minDist)
            {
                minDistObject = childGo;
                minDist = dist;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("mindistance: " + minDistObject.name, minDistObject.gameObject);
        return minDistObject;
    }
```

Comment: The code looks fine. My suspect is that you are not considering the overall set of possible objects, in your for cycle (consider that childCount just returns first level children, and not eventual ones in deeper levels of the hierarchy).

Comment: there is not deeper child

Comment: If you add logging in your loop, what kinds of values is it getting back for the eventual shortest distance it chooses? Is the calculated distance to the correct object not as expected? Some more details on the situation would help narrow down the problem.